# Moveit Tutorials Error Unable to get end effector tips from jmg

Tags: rviz, moveit2

currently I am tring to do Moveit2 tutorials with my custom robot that is created from setup_assistant. I am at [this](https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/tutorials/planning_around_objects/planning_around_objects.html) object avoidance tutorial. At the cpp file written here, there is a constract that calls publishTrajectoryLine to draw the path created. However, I can not see the path in the rviz and in terminal I got an error says:

```
[ERROR] [1711449252.722555690] [moveit_visual_tools]: Unable to get end effector tips from jmg
```

Also related part to code:

```
  auto const draw_trajectory_tool_path =
      [&moveit_visual_tools,
      jmg = move_group_interface.getRobotModel()->getJointModelGroup(
          "maniplator")](auto const trajectory) {
        moveit_visual_tools.publishTrajectoryLine(trajectory , jmg , rvt::LIME_GREEN);
      };
```

Moreover my end effector configuration is:

```
 <!--END EFFECTOR: Purpose: Represent information about an end effector.-->
    <end_effector name="maniplator" parent_link="motor_7_1" group="maniplator"/>
```